# Hide TimeZone showing on DateTime field in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

The date time fields of our CRM instance are showing date along with time and timezone. This is happening since today. Not able to figure out what setting could have been changed to bring this behaviour.

Can anyone shed any light on why this would be happening?

[image]

Comment: Is this in Crm or portal?

Comment: This is in CRM online instance.

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: Is a Custom Entity o Native? if is native, which entity is it? (this got interesting :) )